# Google Sheets: VLOOKUP Using Named Range Fails

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I'm using Coingecko to get cryptocurrency prices, and update the data using a 1 hourly Trigger. As the IMPORTDATA function often fails (a known issue using Coingecko), I have a second Trigger than copies this data as a 'backup', using CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES.

The primary data is Named Range 'Crypto_Data', the backup is 'Crypto_DataBackup', and the cell's formula is:

```
=iferror( vlookup(F24,"Crypto_Data",2,false), vlookup(F24,"Crypto_DataBackup",2,false) )
```

However, the vlookup to "Crypto_DataBackup" fails as it "evaluates to an out of bound range". It works **AOK** if I just substitute the range of the Named Range (CryptoData!M3:W502).

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: The named range does not need to be enclosed in quotation marks. Change your formula like this: `vlookup(F24,Crypto_Data,2,false)`

Comment: Thanks Sergey, working fine now without the quotes.

Comment: I am glad that my answer was useful to you

Answer (score 2):

but if you like quotation marks use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F24, INDIRECT("Crypto_Data"),       2, ), 
         VLOOKUP(F24, INDIRECT("Crypto_DataBackup"), 2, ))
```

also, why not:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(F24, {Crypto_Data; Crypto_DataBackup}, 2, ))
```

Comment: I have a memory like a sieve: I've used named ranges before in vlookups - just forgot I'm not supposed to use quotes.

Like your second suggestion using IFNA, will try that!  :)

Answer (score 1):

As **@Sergey** pointed out: "The named range does not need to be enclosed in quotation marks. Change your formula like this: vlookup(F24,Crypto_Data,2,false)"